# integrate rtk with react-router loader and useRevalidator

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, rtk-query

I'm using the react-router loader with RTK queries. When I perform a mutation that requires invalidation, I need to re-run the loader using useRevalidator from react-router.

The problem is that the loader runs while the invalidatesTags process is still ongoing. I've tried dispatching `getRunningQueriesThunk` to wait for pending queries to finish, but it returns an empty array even though there are pending queries in the state.

```
export const loader = ({ dispatch, state }) => ({ params }) => {
  console.log(state.api)
   /*
  {
   ...
   "queries": [{
        "getBook..": {
           "status": "pending",
           "endpointName": "getBook",
            ....
       },
       ....
    }]
  */


  await Promise.all(dispatch(api.util.getRunningQueriesThunk())) // return [] empty array
  
  try {
    const promise = dispatch(endpoint.getBook(...)
    cont response = await promise.unwrap();
    return {
       layoutTitle: response.title
     }
   } finally {
    promise.unsubscribe()
  }
}


export const Page = () => {
  const { data } = useGetBookQuery();
  const [update] = useUpdateBookMutation();
  const revalidator = useRevalidator();

 const handleUpdate = async () => {
  await update()
  revalidator.revalidate();
 }

  return (
     <div>
        <button onClick={handleUpdate}> update </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause of your problem, but the code can't `await` the `update` call if `handleUpdate` is not declared `async`. Outside of this, I've not found the RRD Data APIs to be very RTKQ friendly and prefer to use the RTKQ hooks the old-fashioned way in the React components. What is loader function doing that you can't just do in the React component where you are using the RTKQ hooks anyway? It seems you are creating unnecessary extra work and making things more complicated than they need to be.

Comment: @DrewReese the code snippet is pseudo code, I will fix this. we have a parent layout with title and breadcrumbs,  so i'm using react router loader for that

Comment: Otherwise I am inclined to agree with @DrewReese. Seems like there is little point in trying to jump through hoops to make RTKQ work with RRD loaders. If I had to start over, I might just use TanStack Query + Router together, since it seems they are somewhat designed to work together. As it is, I'm just going to switch to use RTKQ hooks directly in components.